# How to get a specific Column list from List in Java without looping

Tags: java

I have a list retrieved from the database for which I would like to get all the data of a particular column

```
 List<Contact> contacts = service.getContacts();
```

Say this is how my Contact class look like

```
 class Contact {
      private String userName;
      private String userId;
      private String accNumber;
}
```

How do I get the list of accNumbers from the retrieved contacts list without looping through it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way of doing this without a loop. One possible solution is to filter the results according to your needs in your query itself but database will also use loop so you are kinda stuck.

Comment: you can achieve that by updating the database query to select only that column

Answer (score 2):

You basically *can't* do that, not without some kind of iteration.  But, streams make it easy enough to do this:

```
List<String> accNumbers = contacts.stream()
                                  .map(c -> c.getAccNumber())
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Streams still do iteration under the hood, but at least it hides some of the verbosity of using explicit loops.

Comment: Streams use loop under the hood

Comment: Um...my answer clearly says that there is no way to do this without iteration.  I will add a statement to my answer that streams loop under the hood.